# ExtJS 6. Unable to add a node to a treepanel

Tags: javascript, extjs

For some reason, in `ExtJS 6` I cannot do something that worked literally for years with previous versions of the library. I cannot add a new node to a selected one. This is the code I have:

```
//tree.store.getRootNode().insertBefore(node, tree.store.getRootNode().firstChild);
// ^^^ this works. Nodes are added to the root
selected.insertBefore(node, selected.firstChild);
// ^^^ this does not work, even though "selected" is just an ordinary node
// with leaf = false
```

If I check "selected" node and "selected.firstChild", I see what I expect to see - just normal nodes:

```
console.log(selected); // <-- I see that it is indeed the node, I selected
console.log(selected.firstChild); // <-- it's ok.
```

Comment: I'm not sure. Probably, I should do some kind of refresh - refresh tree view or something like that. I do not know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the node is added, the parent remains collapsed. Maybe that's why you can't see it. Try expanding the parent node. Example:

```
selected.insertBefore(node, selected.firstChild);
selected.expand();
```

Or maybe selected is a leaf node (not allowing children). You would have to `selected.set('leaf', false)` Please take a look at [this working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/15c1)

Comment: It is not the case. I first expand the node, select it and then add to it.

Comment: Otherwise, `console.log(selected.firstChild);` will show something unexpected.

Comment: Thanks! It seems like I have a build with some bugs in it.

Comment: Which build do you have?